# Trying to create a custom fuction using app script that can automatically copy formula to respective row or column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a custom function using an app script that can automatically copy formula to respective rows or columns.

Closest I could find is "Onedit" but it is not provided with a function like an array formula which does the same job for arrays. On edit copies any formula I put in the sheet to all rows... What if I want to copy that formula in specific ranges only?  Cant it be done through a custom function?

A sample table is provided below. I need a formula that can copy formula in all rows below automatically using a custom function.

[image]

formula i use in cell above that gives 366,335 as as below. It super complex so do not support array formula. i expect formula to change cell references as it is copied to different cells.

```
=if(sumifs(indirect(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$6,$A$55:$AB$55,0))&":"&LEFT(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$6,$A$55:$AB$55,0)),2)),indirect(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$8,$A$55:$H$55,0),4)&":"&LEFT(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$8,$A$55:$H$55,0),4),1)),$B14,indirect(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$9,$A$55:$H$55,0),4)&":"&LEFT(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$9,$A$55:$H$55,0),4),1)),C$13,$B$56:$B,">"&$B$7,$B$56:$B,"="&$C$7)=0,"",sumifs(indirect(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$6,$A$55:$AB$55,0))&":"&LEFT(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$6,$A$55:$AB$55,0)),2)),indirect(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$8,$A$55:$H$55,0),4)&":"&LEFT(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$8,$A$55:$H$55,0),4),1)),$B14,indirect(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$9,$A$55:$H$55,0),4)&":"&LEFT(Address(match($P$55,$P$1:$P$55,0)+1,match($B$9,$A$55:$H$55,0),4),1)),C$13,$B$56:$B,">"&$B$7,$B$56:$B,"<="&$C$7))
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a sample sheet with your expected output? I was wondering why do you need a custom function instead of using an array formula. In addition, when you mean copy formula do you intend to copy the formula as it is? or should the reference cell in the formula should adjust based on the row index? I would appreciate if if you could also include the code you used when you tried onedit for reference. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: hi.. thanks for reply. but my formula is very complex. it do not support array functions..

i have updated th question with function i used in cell giving 366,335...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set cell value using custom formula. You might want to consider using custom menu with a [custom dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)

### Sample Code:

**CopyFormulaPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
    function Submit(){
      var src = document.getElementById("source").value;
      var dst = document.getElementById("destination").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).CopyFormula(src,dst);
    }

    function onSuccess(){
      var inDiv = document.getElementById('input');
      var outDiv = document.getElementById('output');
      outDiv.innerHTML = 'Formula copied successfully';
      inDiv.innerHTML = '';
    }

  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div><br>
    <div id="input">
      <label for="source">Source Range:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="source" name="source"><br><br>
      <label for="destination">Destination Range:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination"><br><br>
      <button onclick='Submit()'>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Copy Formula', 'ShowDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function ShowDialog(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CopyFormulaPage')
      .setWidth(300)
      .setHeight(180);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Copy Formula Dialog');
}

function CopyFormula(src,dst){
  Logger.log(src+" "+dst);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dstRange = sheet.getRange(dst);
  sheet.getRange(src).copyTo(dstRange);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get source range and destination range from the custom dialog. Then run `CopyFormula()` in the server with [success handlers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) using `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()`
2. Get the destination range.
3. Get the source range then use [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) to copy the formula to your destination range

### Output

[image]

- I noticed in your based formula that most of the cell references were locked besides `$B14`. As shown in the output, the copied cell adjusts the unlocked reference to `$B15`, `$B16`, and so on..

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues or if this solution doesn't resolve your concern so i could update accordingly

Comment: Hi Ron. Thanks alot for the solution. However I have a last question. Can onedit some how be used here. Like an onedit function? If not then I guess there is no automatic solution to my problem..:(

Comment: How do you plan to trigger onedit? my idea is it is still possible using onEdit(). The difference would be you need to parse your input in the cell in such way that you can read that it is for copying formula, the cell reference of the formula and the range. Example, i will write copyformula,a1,a2:a5 or copyformula(a1,a2:a5). then you need to check the value of the modified cell in the onedit if it contains "copyformula" string. then read the cell references as string to get a1 and a2:a5

Comment: But then again, it is just similar with the answer provided, we just changed the way of reading the source range and the target range via custom dialog box

Comment: Thanks alot. I think I figured out a solution. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1):

I think you should debug it yourself step by step.

Remove all `$` before each row number except those act as header row or a constant cell.

To apply with Google Apps Script.

The simplest way is to create with [setFormulas(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas).

The second way would the using `replace` to replace the row number of existing formula but the conditional is that you only added `$` to those rows do not change.

---

You should be looking for [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en).

It works by putting a single formula like this in `B2`.

`onEdit` is not needed in this case.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,Data!A:B,2,FALSE)))
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for reply. but my formula is very complex. it do not support array functions..

Comment: Updated. Please check.